# HP Zbook G3 Mobile workstation not turning on after

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, hp

I am having a HP Zbook G3 Mobile workstation, i was working with that and forgot to plugin it in to charge, the laptop eventually turned off when it was out of battery, after that laptop is not booting up.

When i plugin the power adapter the led near power connector of laptop is lit and the power button keeps blinking continuously in white colour.

I tried removing the battery and plugging it to power adapter and turning but has the same issue.

Do someone has a solution to this issue.

Comment: Plug it in and leave it for 60 minutes to permit basic charging.

Comment: Tried that for more than 2 hours

Comment: We had the same issue with a zbook. We finally pushed the power button once and walked away and it came back eventually. I think these are just really slow machines.

Answer (score 0):

> I was working with that and forgot to plugin it in to charge .... When
> I plugin the power adapter the led near power connector of laptop is
> lit and the power button keeps blinking continuously in white colour.

Given your tests, it appears that either the battery or the charging circuit has failed.

The only practical action at this point is to have the machine serviced to determine what the problem is.

If uneconomical to repair, and since the computer is about 5 years old, then it may be appropriate to replace it now.

Comment: G3 is out of warranty (model is over 5 years old). Service might be unavailable or excessively expensive.

Comment: I added the potential need to replace the machine

Answer (score 0):

If you tried turning it on with the charger connected but the battery disconnected, then the issue likely isn't the battery but rather the computer's hardware. I will include info for both battery and hardware anyways. Particularly because a laptop frying its power management simply because it discharged, would be odd. Try them in this order.

**Computer**:
With the battery **and** power adapter **disconnected**, push and hold the power button for 15 seconds. This removes residual power from the device. I've seen this trick work on many systems experiencing the same issue you're describing.

**Battery**: It is possible to jump start a li-ion battery. This usually only works if the battery was left unattended for long periods of time and rarely works. I recommend first checking the voltage of the battery with a multimeter. If it doesn't have any voltage, you're a good candidate. If you don't have a multimeter, you can still jump it, but should take precaution.

You can take a 9v battery or another laptop battery and connect positive to positive, negative to negative. You should only do this for 1-2 seconds, disconnect and test for functionality. Leaving the battery connected can result in overcharging, bulging, leaking, explosion.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience at the office with zBooks. I've seen this problem before.

First thing is to make sure you have the proper power-supply. You'll need a 120W or more. The 90W PSU's will not be able to get the laptop out of a deep discharge even though the laptop would normally work with one.

Disconnect all external devices. Also the Thunderbolt dock if you have one. Just the laptop and the PSU.

Disconnect the PSU. And remove the battery.
Press AND hold the laptops powerbutton for a minimum of 15 seconds to totally discharge any remaining power in he circuits.
Re-install the battery and connect the PSU.
Press AND hold the power-button on the keyboard for at least 30 seconds and release it.
Wait 10 seconds and give a short press on the power-button.
If it powers on just leave it powered on to re-charge for at least 2 hours before doing anything else: Problem is solved.
If it doesn't power on leave it sitting for at least 2 hours and try to start it again.
Either that works or it doesn't.

In rare cases you may get an error on screen during this procedure telling you what is wrong. Make a photo of that error screen if you get one so you can show it to support if you need to raise a support call.

If none of that helps it is highly likely the charging circuitry is damaged and the motherboard will need replacing.

Given the age of the laptop a costly repair might make no sense in this case...